# Is my question likely to be closed as poor quality/subjective?

Tags: discussion, support

When I as posting my question I got a popup that my question *appears subjective and is likely to be closed*.

Here is the question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27398297/t-sql-best-way-to-handle-weekdays-and-times-in-job-execution-script

So should I modify the title or is there something else I should write to get advice and helpful suggestions to improve my code?

Comment: Asking for a "best way" is frowned upon for a number of reasons (tl;dr version: too broad, opinion based, nobody should recomment a "bad way" anyways). Furthermore, asking "is this correct" is not very constructive as you're basically asking other people to test your code for you. Did you test it yourself? Do you have any indication to believe it might not be correct? (In the specific case, your check that the time is between 6:30 and 8 is incorrect - which you should have tested).

Comment: Hi, I have tested it, yes, but wanted some advice, I will edit the question so it conforms better to the site standards

Comment: recommended reading: [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/165773)

Comment: Asking for advice is primarily opinion based and qualify for closing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have working code and are looking to improve it, you can go to Code Review.

Such questions, without any specific focus point of what needs improving, are not on topic on SO.

Comment: thanks, I have closed the question anyway, and in future will try Code Review